# Lora sx1278 implementation by Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, wireless, transceiver, c++, lora

I'm implementing a Lora network, with two SX1278 modules and Arduino Uno. Lora is based on three classes. A , B and C, The question is : for change For example A to B, what should exactly change in communication? and How does it change the beacon?. I clearly mean, Does it need to send a particular and standard message to the receiver ? Or Will just communicating in scheduled time change the class or changing some control bits is needed?

Comment: what do you mean by class?

Comment: LoRa has three classes, class A (scheduled one side )
,class B ( becean mode) , class C (continuous)